# Как найти номер недели в квартале и месяце?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

В коде ниже к фрейму данных делаю обозначения для каждой строки дня, недели, месяца, квартала.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).day
df['week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).week
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
df['quarter'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).quarter
```

А как получить значения:

1. Неделя квартала - то есть в каждом квартале есть определенное кол-во недель
   Например 7/21/1959 - "8" неделя
2. Неделя месяца - аналогично, но в каждом месяце 4-5 недель находится
   Например 7/21/1959 - "3" неделя

[Ссылка на файл](https://dropmefiles.com/UCFqV).

```
Date
7/21/1959
7/22/1959
7/23/1959
7/24/1959
7/27/1959
7/28/1959
7/29/1959
7/30/1959
7/31/1959
08.03.1959
08.04.1959
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: По какому правилу вы хотите нумеровать недели? Например по правилам ISO первой неделей __в году__ считается та, на которую выпадает минимум четыре дня нового года или первая неделя в году, содержащая четверг.

Comment: Если 1е число месяца приходится на субботу - как считать эту неделю - как последнюю неделю предыдущего месяца или как первую текущего?? Тоже самое для квартала?

Comment: `"1е число - 1я неделя до Воскресенья"` - что это значит?

Comment: Конкретный пример - какой номер недели в квартале должен быть у `30.09.2021` и у `01.10.2021` ?   ;)

Comment: Если вы будете отвечать "да" на вопрос, содержащий "или" - так мы никуда не продвинемся. Вопрос: вы мужчина или женщина? Ответ: "да". :-D

Comment: можете пояснить как 30.09.21 оказалось __пятой__ неделей 3го квартала?? Когда у вас квартал начинается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Читаем данные:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=["Date"])
```

Неделя квартала:

```
df["week_of_quarter"] = df["Date"].dt.isocalendar()["week"] // 4 + 1
```

Неделя месяца:

```
df["week_of_month"] = df["Date"].dt.isocalendar()["week"] // 12 + 1
```

результат:

```
In [96]: df
Out[96]:
          Date  week_of_quarter  week_of_month
0   1959-07-21                8              3
1   1959-07-22                8              3
2   1959-07-23                8              3
3   1959-07-24                8              3
4   1959-07-27                8              3
..         ...              ...            ...
914 1963-03-06                3              1
915 1963-03-07                3              1
916 1963-03-08                3              1
917 1963-03-11                3              1
918 1963-03-12                3              1

[919 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

Пример для `01.01.2021`, `30.09.2021` и `01.10.2021`:

```
In [98]: d.isocalendar()["week"] // 4
Out[98]:
2021-01-01    13
2021-09-30     9
2021-10-01     9
Name: week, dtype: UInt32

In [99]: d.isocalendar()["week"] // 12
Out[99]:
2021-01-01    4
2021-09-30    3
2021-10-01    3
Name: week, dtype: UInt32
```

Comment: @kocwab, выполните код из ответа как есть (не меняя ничего), включая первую команду для парсинга  CSV файла...